# RSS with link to actual post

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am using the following php code to load a rss feed from a wordpress site of mine into another, however it doesn't get the links to the actual post which is a problem for me and I can't seem to fix it.

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/rss.xml');

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $title       = (string) $item->title;
  $description = (string) $item->description;

  print '<div class="entry">';

  printf(
    '<h2>%s</h2><p>%s</p>', 
    $title, 
    $description
  );

  if ($media = $item->children('media', TRUE)) {
    if ($media->content->thumbnail) {
      $attributes = $media->content->thumbnail->attributes();
      $imgsrc     = (string)$attributes['url'];

      printf('<div><img src="%s" alt="" /></div>', $imgsrc);
    }
  }

  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After Reading a bit about the XML Structure of the RSS Feed i was able to edit the code above into which gives a nice and easy RSS embeder :)

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://presstv.bg/?feed=rss');

foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  $link     = (string) $item->link;
  $title       = (string) $item->title;
  $description = (string) $item->description;

  print '<div class="entry">';

  printf(
    '<a href="%s"><h2>%s</h2></a><p>%s</p>',
    $link,
    $title, 
    $description
  );

  if ($media = $item->children('media', TRUE)) {
    if ($media->content->thumbnail) {
      $attributes = $media->content->thumbnail->attributes();
      $imgsrc     = (string)$attributes['url'];

      printf('<div><img src="%s" alt="" /></div>', $imgsrc);
    }
  }
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```